# Need help adding data to excel from Python

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl, pprint
import pandas as pd
import os
```

After going through everything

```
my_list = []
for j in range(2, 8):
    my_list.append(sheet1.cell(row = 7, column = j).value)
print(my_list)
```

I get the following

```
[1941533, 1002, 0.0005160870301972719, 8523, 1937, 479367.6439999999]
```

I now want to add each element from my list to excel

```
for j in range(13,20):
    sheet3.cell(row = 22, column = j)
```

So I want my_list[0] to = row 22 and column 13 in excel and so on up to J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the biggest problems you'll encounter with your code is that `my_list` has a length of 6, so your second for loop would need to be `for j in range(14,20):` or `for j in range(13,19):`.

I've provided a fully reproducible example below. It creates an example workbook called test_1.xlsx, then reads it in and creates a new workbook called test_2.xlsx which has the a second sheet has the list elements added in the row and columns you specified in your question.

```
import openpyxl, pprint
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# The next four lines create a sample excel file called test_1.xlsx
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15, 12), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.close()

wb = load_workbook('test_1.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']
my_list = []
for j in range(2, 8):
    my_list.append(sheet1.cell(row = 7, column = j).value)
print(my_list)

wb.create_sheet('Sheet3')
sheet3 = wb['Sheet3']
for j in range(13,19):
    sheet3.cell(row = 22, column = j).value = my_list[j-13]
wb.save("test_2.xlsx")
```

Comment: `my_list = [cell.value for cell in ws[22][2:8]]`